# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.name"

Tags: android-studio

Good Day,

I am having trouble on this error and I am unable to find way how to fix it. I change my package from **com.utok.ph** to **quiznew.utok.ph** but as you can see in the error it will call the (**com.utok.ph.quiznew.utok.ph**)

[image]

Comment: it's clear where the error is, try to rectify it at the line pointed out

Comment: were I can find the DexPath List?

Comment: by the way I was able to figure it out thanks @ADITYARANADE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at my AndroidManifest.xml and try also this one.

- Go To Build
- Clean Project